# jQuery Mobile custom icon not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, icons

Somehow I can't get a custom ui-icon to show up. In this example the two image files (18x18 and 36x36 px) are in the same directory as the html file. Can anyone spot what's wrong here? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>-</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/theme-classic/theme-classic.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

    <style style="text/css">
        .ui-icon-dbblue {
            background-image: url("dbblue.png");
        }

        @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
            .ui-icon-dbblue {
                    background-image: url("dbblue_hr.png");
                    background-size: 18px 18px;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-title="Control" id="control" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="dbblue" data-iconpos="notext" title="dbblue"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All looks in order to be honest?

Comment: So standard icon is shown instead?

Comment: @Regent It's just a dark grey button without any icon really.

Comment: SIze of ur icon should be 18*18

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add !important in your css.

```
 <style style="text/css">
    .ui-icon-dbblue {
        background-image: url("dbblue.png") !important;
    }

    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        .ui-icon-dbblue {
                background-image: url("dbblue_hr.png") !important;
                background-size: 18px 18px !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: if u override existing icon, you can use important. But it is a new icon. SO important wont work.

Comment: @Raj have you tried it or just speculating? Please try it. It works.

Comment: That actually worked. I had tried it with the addition of "no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;" which I found somewhere else, but that didn't work. !important alone works. Now the "only" problem is that the icon isn't at the correctly placed on the button and gets repeated. "no-repeat !important;" doesn't work though, the icon is then not displayed at all.

Comment: To use no-repeat you have to use it as 
background: url("dbblue.png") no-repeat !important;
instead of background-image. But still you have to place image correctly. I think using background instead of background-image will just resolve "icon not displayed" issue.

Comment: Yea, you're right. I've got the icon to show and also to show up in the center of the button where it belongs using the following code:

    .ui-icon-dreambox-blue {
            background-image: url("/static/images/dreambox-blue.png") !important;
       background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: center !important;
    }

The only problem is that the button itselfs looks different than other buttons that use standard icons. The custom button is "flat", the others have a somewhat round look. Here's an image of what I mean: [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/s2uzw6.png)

Comment: So what could be the better solution for this ? As per my knowledge here we need to override background property of .ui-btn class.